# Office web addin does not show up in the "Admin Managed" Office add-ins tab for some users in the organization

Tags: office365, office-js

My word office addin has been deployed via the Office 365 Admin admin centre. Some users in my organization cannot add the addin. They cannot see the same when they try to manually add the addin via the Word Online menu options. When I deployed the addin via Centralized Deployment I had selected access for Everyone. Is there any additional user rights or user access that is linked with web addins.